# Release COM when developing an Excel Addin?

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-interop, excel-addins

I understand that I should release COM objects when using interop.  Are things a bit different when developing and Add-In, Excel for example?  Here is a loop I have and I was curious to know if the `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` is necessary?

```
 foreach (var sheet in results.Sheets)
            {
                var newSheet = workbook.AddSheet();

                newSheet.SetSheetTabColor(sheet.TabColor);
                newSheet.SetSheetName(sheet.TabName);
                newSheet.Cells.SetFont("Calibri", 8);
                newSheet.FreezeRow(1);

                var endRow = sheet.Data.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
                var endColumn = sheet.Data.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;

                var writeRange = newSheet.SetWriteRange(1, 1, endRow, endColumn);



                writeRange.Value2 = sheet.Data;

                newSheet.AutoFitColumns();
                newSheet.RemoveColumn(1);

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newSheet);

            }
```

Also, I created a library with extension methods.  One example is `workbook.AddSheet()`  `AddSheet` looks like this:

```
public static Worksheet AddSheet(this Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook)
        {
            var sheets = workbook.Sheets;

            return sheets.Add(After: sheets[sheets.Count]);
        }
```

Since I am accessing `sheets` from `workbook.Sheets`, do I have to release of this object?  If so where since I am returning a Worksheet?  I can't release before I return?

This may be a dumb question, but if the `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` was not necessary in the foreach scope, does it hurt even if it is still there?

Answer (score 2):

`Marshal.ReleaseComObject` is used only if you need to control the lifetime of an COM object in timely manner, or in specific order. For casual usage of COM objects i **would not** advice you to use this method at all.

Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This method is used to explicitly control the lifetime of a COM object
>   used from managed code. You should use this method to free the
>   underlying COM object that holds references to resources in a timely
>   manner or when objects must be freed in a specific order.

About your second question

> Since I am accessing sheets from workbook.Sheets, do I have to release
>   of this object? If so where since I am returning a Worksheet? I can't
>   release before I return?

The COM implementation in .NET is using reference counting mechanism to detect if object is used or not, so **NO** you don't have to release anything explicitly. The framework is resposible for this.

**NOTE:**
Use the approriate .`Close`(for **Workbook**), .`Quit`(for **Application**) methods for proper release of resurces. When you use .`Quit`() over the application object you will close the excel process in windows (so this will release all resource), and .`Close`() over a Workbook to release file locks .. etc over specific excel file.

Comment: In my case, the user opens excel first and runs an addin on the existing file, but they usually don't close it until they want to, so in this case, I don't have to call close or quit, correct?

Comment: Correct, in addin scenarios this is not neceserry. The user will close the application.