# Is it necessary to release ComObject if I close the app in c#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, garbage-collection, marshalling, comobject

I have the following code, I wonder if I need to release `ComObject` manually or the garbage collector will release it for me?

```
wordApp = new Word.Application();
wordDoc = new Word.Document();
// some stuff

wordDoc.Close(null, null , null);
wordApp.Quit();
if(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.IsComObject(wordDoc))
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordDoc);
wordDoc = null;
if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.IsComObject(wordApp))
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);
wordApp = null;
```

Is the above code correct or shouldn't I use `Marshal.IsComObject` in the end?

Comment: Why do you have to call the same code twice?

Comment: You don't have to release it explicitly just setting it to null will GC it

Comment: There is no point in IsComObject(), you know it is one.  ReleaseComObject() has little point as well, manual memory management rarely comes to a good end.  But especially no point when closing the app, the CLR runs the finalizers before shutting down and that always takes care of any RCW.

Comment: @HansPassant so remove the two if and just set them to null is sufficient in this case.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't, but my experience with automating Office apps says that you would better. :-)

Comment: @Nick that's what I don't understand, from reading online some people suggest it is better to release it manually and some say it is better to leave it for the garbage collector.

Comment: No, setting the variable to null is pointless as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034

Comment: @LionKing, in case of Word / Office, I strongly recommend that you manually release them.  If you leave it to the GC, it may not release the objects when you expect and that will lead to Word processes running in memory.  That can cause also further trouble when you invoke Word next time.

Comment: @HansPassant I am getting different explanation from Nick (and some other articles I found online https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/05/release-excel-com-objects/)

Comment: This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926633/release-com-when-developing-an-excel-addin/47927022#47927022. In short .. the recommendation from msdn documentation is not to do it explicitly in general, only if you really need to release the resources in specific order or timely manner.

Comment: How do you think the answers will differ from your question from yesterday?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 that was regarding the behavior of `List.Clear()` with `ComObject`, this is about if it is a good practice to release them manually or not.

Comment: You should release them manually - *all* of them - in the reverse order they were instantiated. So `wordDoc` before `wordApp` for example. And it's also not a bad idea to invoke GC.Collect; GC.WaitForImpendingFinalizers; - twice in succession. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa679807(v=office.11).aspx)